# Работа со сложным массивом в AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android

У меня список стран хранится в XML, так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="nation_array">
    <item>Afghanistan</item>
    <item>Albania</item>
    <item>Algeria</item>
    <item>American Samoa</item>
    <item>Andorra</item>
    <item>Angola</item>
    <item>Anguilla</item>
    <item>Antarctica</item>
    ................
</string-array>
</resources>
```

**Адаптер:**

```
String[] countries = groupContent.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nation_array);
ArrayAdapter<String> nationAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(mContext, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countries);

autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(nationAdapter);
```

И все нормально работает. Но теперь так получилось, что нужно в выпадающем списке показывать название стран, но при отправке использовать двузначные аббревиатуры стран, типа Russia - RU.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<country-list>
<country>
    <name>Абхазия</name>
    <english>Abkhazia</english>
    <code>AB</code>
</country>
<country>
    <name>Австралия</name>
    <english>Australia</english>
    <code>AU</code>
</country>
<country>
    <name>Австрия</name>
    <english>Austria</english>
    <code>AT</code>
</country>
<country>
    <name>Азербайджан</name>
    <english>Azerbaijan</english>
    <code>AZ</code>
</country>
.............
</country-list>
```

**Вопрос:** Как все это реализовать, подскажите? Нигде такие примеры не нашел

Comment: если мой ответ вам подошел, отметьте его верным, поставив галочку

Comment: Только прочитал, сейчас проверю...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно отправлять двузначные аббревиатуры, в зависимости от выбранной страны. Смотрите:

```
//массив стран и аббревиатур
String[] countries = {"Россия", "США", " Украина"};
String[] abbr = {"RU", "US", "UK"};

//заполням AutoCompleteTextView массивом стран
ArrayAdapter<String> nationAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(mContext, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countries);
autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(nationAdapter);

Button ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.go);
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
//берем выбранный текст страны
String countryName = autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString();
//узнаем позицию
int posi = Arrays.asList(countries).indexOf(countryName);
//по этой позиции берем аббревиатуру из массива
String abbrv = abbr[posi];
//Ну и покажем 
Toast.makeText(this, countries[posi] + " - " + abbrv, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 });
```

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=-1`  Где
              `String abbrv = abbr[posi];`

Comment: @TITAN, Замените на `String abbrv = abbr[posi++];`Хотя, у меня все работает :)